# How to precondition FEM problems using domain decomposition?

Tags: finite-element, domain-decomposition

Let's say that I have a FEM code which yields the following problem:
$$
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}.
$$
In order to solve this more efficiently with an iterative method, I would like to precondition it,
$$
\mathbf{BAx} = \mathbf{Bb},
$$
using domain decomposition. This is a common application for domain decomposition methods. My question is: How do I retrieve $\mathbf{B}$ from a Schwarz domain decomposition method?

For example, the alternating Schwarz algorithm for the Poisson problem first solves this problem:
$$
-\nabla^2u=f\quad\rm{in}\ \Omega_1,\\
u_1^n=g\quad \rm{on}\ \partial\Omega_1\backslash\Gamma_1,\\
u_1^n=u_2^{n-1}|_{\Gamma_1}
$$

and then solves this problem:
$$
-\nabla^2u=f\quad\rm{in}\ \Omega_2,\\
u_2^n=g\quad \rm{on}\ \partial\Omega_2\backslash\Gamma_2,\\
u_2^n=u_1^{n-1}|_{\Gamma_2}
$$
where $\Omega = \Omega_1\cup \Omega_2$ is the global domain, and $\Gamma_i$ denotes the part of the boundary which overlaps the other subdomain. By solving these equations repeatedly, I get better and better estimates for the global solutions $u_1$ and $u_2$. Let's now say I want to use this to precondition $\mathbf{Ax} = \mathbf{b}$, how do I do that? How do I get the $\mathbf{B}$ matrix mentioend earlier from these solutions?

Ultimately, I am also interested in additive Schwarz and multiplicative Schwarz.

Answer (score 2):

Let us consider the abstract linear problem
$$ \mathcal{A} x = b \,, $$
where $\mathcal{A}$ is a linear operator and $x$ and $b$ some functions on a
certain domain.

To answer your question let me first discuss, what a preconditioner is
supposed to do. A preconditioner is choosen such that
$\mathcal{B} \approx \mathcal{A}^{-1}$, implying that
$\mathcal{B} \mathcal{A} \approx I$, which is a system that is easy to solve.

It is important to note that
a preconditioner should compute approximations to
$\mathcal{A}^{-1} b$ for
*any* possible right hand side $b$.
The question now is, what corresponds to $b$ in your problem.

In a general situation $b$ is the input of the problem you are solving,
i.e. $b$ consists of $f$ and the boundary function $g$. Let us for simplicity,
however, assume that $g=0$, and therefore, the input of the preconditioner is
only the function $f$.

In this situation $\mathcal{B} b$
is the result of performing a few steps of
the alternating Schwarz procedure with right hand side $f=b$,
starting with some (prefarably zero) initial iterate.

Hence, if you want to obtain the matrix $B$, you have to write down the matrix
that represents this procedure on your space of piecewise polynomial
functions. The right hand side $b$ ($ = f$), will be some some piecewise
polynomial function.

Comment: Are you aware of any papers or books which show how to do this (in general)? For common algorithms like the alternating Schwarz, I expect it to be well known how to do it.

Comment: You can look at Toselli and Widlund *Domain Decomposition Methods -- Algorithms and Theory*. There is a section called "Block Jacobi Preconditioners" that covers some of the details.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use domain decomposition methods. They're from the 1990s, but we have much better ways of preconditioning problems today. All of them work on the *global* problem, rather than ones on subdomains. One example are algebraic multigrid methods.

Comment: This is good know, although my interest in using domain decomposition methods for preconditioning is only because I find it interesting. I would still like to know how to do it.